# Force download file and exclude PDF

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to configure my htaccess for force downloading all files except PDF. For this I tried following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?!pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

But this not working. There are many examples for forcing downloads files, but no for excluding…

Comment: Try putting the anchor inside your regex: `\.(?!pdf$)`

Comment: That's new for me, but really works! :)